# Java 8 - Xmx and XX:MaxHeapSize do not match

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I have set the Xmx parameter for JVM to 5120 but when the java process(tomcat) runs, I see that the MaxHeapSize does not match the Xmx value, it is stuck at 2570, which is strange to me, any thoughts on this are much appreciated!!

Output of ps:

> /usr/bin/java -Dnop -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1536m -Xmx5120 -Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -DSHUTDOWN_PORT=8005 -DHTTP_PORT=8080 -DHTTPS_PORT=8443 -DAJP_PORT=8009 -XX:InitialHeapSize=2570m -XX:MaxHeapSize=2570m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/app/tomcat/default -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/app/tomcat/default/temp org.apache.catalina.

Comment: `-Xmx5120` should be `Xmx5120m`

Answer (score 6):

> The -Xmx option is equivalent to -XX:MaxHeapSize.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)

So `-Xmx5120` means **5120 Bytes** but is superseeded by `-XX:MaxHeapSize=2570m`. That is the reason you are stuck by this.

Just provide only one of these settings and choose the proper value, e.g.

```
-Xmx5120m
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems in your config:

> -Xms1536m -Xmx5120

If you don't specify the unit of this config, it will be parsed as `bytes`,  which means your `Xmx` is less than your `Xms`, if this config applies JVM will failed to launch:

```
 ~/ java -Xms1536m -Xmx5120 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

Your JVM did not aborted because you have following configs:

> -XX:InitialHeapSize=2570m -XX:MaxHeapSize=2570m

`-Xms` is `-XX:InitialHeapSize` and `-Xmx` is `-XX:MaxHeapSize`, so your previous wrong config of `-Xms1536m -Xmx5120` is replaced by the later ones, which specified `Xmx` to be 2570M.